Length calculations with ST_LineSubstring (with geometry and geography)
I want to calculate lengths of partial LineStrings. I thought that I could a) use ST_LineSubstring and calculate the length of the substring or b) calculate the length of the whole LineString and multiply it with some fraction. Those methods did not result in the same numbers and while investigating, I found some other unexpected behaviour. Can someone explain what is going on?
I build an example with this statement
CREATE TABLE substrings  AS (

    WITH theEdge AS (
        SELECT ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY[ST_Point(8, 52, 4326), ST_Point(8.1, 52.5, 4326), ST_Point(8.5, 52, 4326)])::geography AS geog
    )
    
    SELECT frac,
        interpolated_geom_point,
        interpolated_geog_point,
        ST_PointN(geom_substring, ST_NPoints(geom_substring)) AS geom_substring_end_point,
        ST_PointN(geog_substring::geometry, ST_NPoints(geog_substring::geometry)) AS geog_substring_end_point,
        geog AS complete_line,
        
        ST_Length(geom_substring::geography) AS geom_substring_length,
        ST_Length(geog_substring) AS geog_substring_length,
    
        ST_Length(geog)*(frac) AS multiplied_length,
        ST_Length(geog) AS total_length
    FROM (
        SELECT frac, geog,
               ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geog::geometry, frac) AS interpolated_geom_point,
               ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geog, frac) AS interpolated_geog_point,
               ST_LineSubstring(geog::geometry, 0, frac) AS geom_substring,
               ST_LineSubstring(geog, 0, frac) AS geog_substring
        FROM (
            SELECT generate_series(0, 1, 0.1) AS frac, geog
            FROM theEdge
        )
    
    )
)

which generates a table like this (omitting the geography and geometry columns):



frac
geom_substring_length
geog_substring_length
multiplied_length
total_length




0
0
0
0
118034.33909165161


0.1
12644.742035627527
11803.43390916582
11803.433909165162
118034.33909165161


0.2
25289.24596292537
23606.86781832942
23606.867818330324
118034.33909165161


0.3
37933.51079658642
35410.301727496255
35410.301727495484
118034.33909165161


0.4
50577.53554752395
47213.735636659716
47213.73563666065
118034.33909165161


0.5
62359.3763091717
61402.72250507259
59017.169545825804
118034.33909165161


0.6
73485.95474904335
82707.54878747578
70820.60345499097
118034.33909165161


0.7
84616.74742546407
104012.37506988208
82624.03736415612
118034.33909165161


0.8
95751.74715761328
118034.33909165161
94427.4712733213
118034.33909165161


0.9
106890.94676983653
118034.33909165161
106230.90518248644
118034.33909165161


1.0
118034.33909165161
118034.33909165161
118034.33909165161
118034.33909165161



This table illustrates the different length calculations. I thought that I should use the geography type for accurate length calculations, but the geography substring function returns the whole linestring for an endfraction >= 0.8. Why? Why is just multiplying the total length different from the substring results? Which method is the correct one?
To get a more complete view of the problem, I visualized the different methods in QGIS using the omitted columns:














The geometry based (green) and geography based (red) functions return completely different results (that was expected). ST_LineInterpolatePoint and ST_LineSubstring result in the same points with geometry (good), but differ in the second part of the string when using geography. Only the points generated by ST_LineInterpolatePoint with geography input seem to be equally spaced. Why doesn't the ST_LineSubstring function return the same results?

Sorry, I can't figure out how to show the images directly within the question :(

No time to look at the implementations of ST_LineSubstring and ST_LineInterpolatePoint, yet; just so much: ST_Length is a static value over the whole length, that you then divide fractionally into equal intervals. The actual geodetic lengths between any of your fractionized coordinates are never equal if they do not follow a parallel (latitude)!

@geozelot thought that ST_LineSubstring would divide the string in a way so that the resulting parts have the size of that fraction, e.g. ST_LineSubstring(geog, 0, 0.4) would result in the first 40% of my linestring (with 40% of the total length). Is that incorrect? If so, what are the start- and endfraction values referring to (since it is not the length)?

ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geog::geometry, frac) AS interpolated_geom_point --> considers cartesian distance, so result is of doubtful meaning in 4326 (midpoint of (0 0; 10 80) is returned as 5 40, but this is not half of the ground length)

ST_Length(geom_substring::geography) AS geom_substring_length, --> this is not the length of the geometry, but of its cast to geography, i.e. a great circle arc using the same start/end points

==> the use of 4326 to compute distance related information, and the back and forth between geometry and geography makes the whole comparison pointless...

That being said, the part of your question about ST_LineSubstring(geography) remains. It could be a bug.

@JGH Thanks for stating that so clearly. You are right, the geometry version will not result in the correct points. It was a workaround when I first discovered that the ST_LineSubstring(geography) behaved weirdly and I reasoned that most of my linestrings are a lot shorter than this example scenario (so the geom/geog difference should be smaller)
